# Deploy updates for code igniter web application

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications

I have a web application written on Code Igniter and almost ready for the release.
I'm looking into ways to do "automatic" updates for the clients.

Now there are going to be versions of the application on which the users will choose to update and when to do it.

I'm curious on how to update the files for the user.
What i used to do before using a framework i used to make a zip file of the new-edited files store it on an FTP and on the user side when he updated i just unziped the file and replace the ones on his side.

For the database schema and other updates i intend to keep a file with the required queries and run during the update.

Should i go with that way or is there something other that i can implement on Code Igniter?
A more straight forward road?

Also i'm still figuring out the part where a user will have to update from say version 1.0.0 to 1.0.3 (2 or 3 versions apart) and the requirements on the files side but on the database also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to put it under version control with Git, you can use PHPloy to push only the latest change to the server through FTP. Check it out on Github: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy

*Disclaimer: I've written PHPloy*